# Segmentation Fault but I can't find it

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is a program that takes the arguments passed by the user, checks if it's a letter, and concatenates them in an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char frase[80] = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s", argv[i]);
        if(isalpha(argv[i]))
            strcat(frase, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", frase);
}
```

I have used `gdb` (also with the core option) and there are no errors, yet I get `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. The code works if I remove `if(isalpha(argv[i]))`. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to isalpha is one character, not a pointer to a string of characters. Passing it a pointer might cause it to reference undefined memory by indexing out of the table of characters it uses.